# Example of index of intersection of subgroup in subgroup not dividing index of subgroup in group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

"Let $G$ be a group and let $H,K$ be finite index subgroups of $G$. Give an example of group and subgroups such that the index of $H\cap K$ in $H$, $[H\cap K:H]$, does not divide the index of $K$ in $G$, $[K:G]$."

I have been breaking my head with this for hours and still cannot find an answer to it. I've searched on the internet but I couldn't find any example of it, just theorems stating that $[H\cap K:H]\leq [G:K]$ ([here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Index_in_Subgroup) if you are interested). Can you come up with any example? Thanks!

Comment: But there is an example of a group $G$ of order $6$ with this property. How can that be so difficult to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a group such that for some prime there is distinct sylow $p$-subgroups and let one be $H$ and the other $K$. Note that $[H\cap K : H] = p^{a}$ with $a>0$ and $[K:G]$ is not a multiple of $p$.

It seems the smallest example is $G= S_3$, $H = \{ e, (1,2) \}$ and $K = \{e, (2,3) \}$ and $H\cap K = \{e\}$. And so the first index is $2$ and the second index is $3$.